# How to run the sql statements incrementally for a given job range

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to frame a query from where i can automate the execution of statements.

Scenario is as below:-

provided with the job and proc range say JOBS from `J63250-J63299` and proc range for same is as below `P632500 - P632999`

Iam trying to run the simple queries as below on different tables.

```sql
Insert into JOB 
(JOB_ID,BTCH_ID,GRP_ID,JOB_GRP_CD,JOB_NM,JOB_DS,JOB_OBJ_TYPE_CD,JOB_ACTV_FLG,LAST_UPDT_TS)
values ('J63251','BCPR_FIX_CUST',null,'SS','run_td_macro.ksh','Load the TMP_ORD_ACTN_DETL table','SS','Y',SYSDATE);

 Insert into JOB 
(JOB_ID,BTCH_ID,GRP_ID,JOB_GRP_CD,JOB_NM,JOB_DS,JOB_OBJ_TYPE_CD,JOB_ACTV_FLG,LAST_UPDT_TS) 
values ('J63252','BCPR_FIX_CUST',null,'SS','run_td_macro.ksh','Load the TMP_ASSG_PROD_DVIC table','SS','Y',SYSDATE);

Insert into JOB 
(JOB_ID,BTCH_ID,GRP_ID,JOB_GRP_CD,JOB_NM,JOB_DS,JOB_OBJ_TYPE_CD,JOB_ACTV_FLG,LAST_UPDT_TS)
values ('J63253','BCPR_FIX_CUST',null,'SS','run_td_macro.ksh','Load the TMP_ASSG_PROD_PARM_DVIC','SS','Y',SYSDATE);
```

I want to achieve a way where  I can define the proc range and job range and want the query execution where it will incrementally pic the job range with all the values till the end and breaks ones the limit values is reached.

Can any one shed some light over here. For any further info required please let me know

Iam currently using the oracle sql developer Version 4.1.3.20

Comment: What exactly is the result you expect from the above input data?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: **Syntax may differ**

You can try [CTE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html)

for exmple:

```
with cte (JOB_ID,BTCH_ID,GRP_ID,JOB_GRP_CD,JOB_NM,JOB_DS,JOB_OBJ_TYPE_CD,JOB_ACTV_FLG,cnt)as
(
    SELECT to_char('J'(10)) as JOB_ID,'BCPR_FIX_CUST',null,'SS','run_td_macro.ksh','Load the TMP_ORD_ACTN_DETL table','SS','Y',cast(63251 as number(10))as cnt

    union all
    SELECT to_char(('J'||to_char(cnt(10)))(10)),BTCH_ID,GRP_ID,JOB_GRP_CD,JOB_NM,JOB_DS,JOB_OBJ_TYPE_CD,JOB_ACTV_FLG,cnt+1 from cte  where cnt<63299

)
select * 
from cte 
where JOB_ID != 'J'
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

instead of  `select *` you may use [SELECT INTO Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm) for bulk insert

Comment: `option (maxrecursion 0);` is invalid for Oracle

Comment: SELECT INTO can only be used inside a PL/SQL procedure, not in plain SQL.

Comment: A link to the MySQL manual seems rather pointless for an Oracle solution